# Complex MongoDB Merge by Max Arbitrary Values

Tags: mongodb, merge, aggregation-framework

I would like to perform a complex merge:

e.g.

```
[
{
“one.two.three”: 4,
“number.two”: “B”
},
{
“one.two.three”: 7,
“number.two”: “A”
},
{
“one.two.three”: 10,
“number.two”: “B”
}
]
```

where the result is:

```
{
“one.two.three”: 10,
“number.two”: “A”
}
```

because those are the maximum values…I could have any N+ number of arbitrary KV pairs, so I can’t just sort on a specific field

Comment: Please explain the logic here

Comment: The results value of “one.two.three” is 10 since it is the max value? Why is the result value of “number.two” is 'A'?

Answer (score 0):

Query

- having field names with `$ or .` is problematic and hard to use, i think you need to change your field names to not contain those characters [see this](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/#std-label-crud-concepts-dot-dollar-considerations)
- group and find the max and min, i guess for letters you wanted the min because you wanted A letter

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6313dd4078a49d878285149a)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$group": 
   {"_id": null,
    "max-one": {"$max": "$one"},
    "max-number": {"$min": "$number"}}}])
```